# Error on importing cv2 and mediapipe in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dllimport, mediapipe

I had installed both opencv-python and mediapipe modules using pip and my python version is 3.10.5, and when I try to just execute below two lines separately:

1. For importing cv2:
   import cv2

then Iam getting the below error
**return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.**

2. for importing mediapipe:
   import mediapipe

then Iam getting the below error
**from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _framework_bindings: The specified module could not be found.**

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem, also I tried changing various versions of both modules by uninstalling and installing it again also I tried it with different versions of python and even I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.10.5, but even though I did get any luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tried to import cv2, mediapipe
And then ran through some errors.

Comment: Those are two different errors, but both mean that you are missing some dependencies of mediapipe.

Comment: can you please help me in installing those dependencies. (Like if possible can you provide me the details of those missing dependencies) Are why is this error coming even after installing visual redistribution c++ 2015-2019.